# How to replace values in dataframe by choosing elements from list at random?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1's and 0's which looks like:

```
Index Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3
A     1          0          1
B     0          1          1
C     0          0          1
```

I also have a list which looks like: {'X','Y','Z'}

I want to replace all '1's in the dataframe with values from the list at random. So the output could look like:

```
Index Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3
A     Y          0          X
B     0          Z          Y
C     0          0          Z
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use np.where and random.choice as

```
import random

yourlist = ['X','Y','Z']
df = df.where(df == 1, random.choice(yourlist))
```

You can also use .replace as

```
df = df.replace(1, random.choice(yourlist))
```

Update:
you are right that we have random.choice same for every replacement, it isnt evaluated for all element?

can you try this and see how it works

```
 df = df.update(np.random.choice(yourlist, size=df.shape), filter_func=lambda x: x==1)
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that random.choice only pick one letter for all replaced rows

Comment: @AlbertoCastillo are you sure ? it is supposed to take random selections

Comment: Yep... I ran your code and all 1 numbers has been replaced by only one letter, random, but just one letter, f.i. 1 by 'X' or 1 by 'Y'. And I think it makes sense due to `replace` and `where` takes all rows = 1 and replace with any letter, all in one step, it's not like iteration... but your answer has been marked as good so I suppose it works for @Thelonius. Cheers!

Comment: @Alberto Castillo Indeed, the issue you described is true. I did not check it properly earlier. The above code replaces each '1' with the same random element from the list

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if it works?

Comment: I tried it, it seems the df returned is of 'NoneType', so I can not open it. Not sure why this is the case.